# TKinter, Python - Creating TopLevel popups using iteration and then closing them again without killing root

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to create a program that allows the user to enter the real names of people from a list of obscure names.

I want the pop-up windows to be generated from a main root window. Once the user has entered the real name, the pop-up should close and then open the next obscure name in the list.

I also want the user to be able to kill the entire iteration by closing the main root window; hence the need for it and not creating an individual pop-up for each name.

I have tried using win.destroy(), this kills the first pop-up but the iteration is also killed and the second name is not opened. I then tried using win.quit() but this left the pop-up windows open and if the information is entered twice it causes the program to crash.

Is it possible to get the pop-up windows to close after assigning the real name without disrupting the iteration?

Here is my code (I have included both the win.quit() and win.destroy() commands I have tried)

```
from Tkinter import *

name_list = ["Jimmy Bob", " Bobby Jim", "Sammy Jim Bob" ] 

def assign():
    print("You chose option %s" %(e1.get()))
    win.destroy()   # Ends the iteration  
    #win.quit()         # Continues the iteration but does not close the     window and crashes if entered twice

root = Tk() 

for i in name_list: 

        win = Toplevel(root)
        win.lift()                                             
        e1 = Entry(win)
        e1.grid(row=1, column=0)
        var = StringVar()
        var.set(i)
        Label(win, textvariable = var).grid(row=0, column=0)
        Button(win, text='Enter Real Name', command=assign).grid(row=2, column=0, pady=4)

        win.mainloop( )

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that `win.mainloop()` is blocking, so having it in the iteration means that nothing will happen until after the win has been closed.

however, just getting rid of `win.mainloop()` causes all of the popups to come up at once so we need a way to make it so that the next iteration only happens once the button has been pressed, this is the reason for the `do_next()` function

the final change I made is the addition of the `quit` function, this duplicates the behavior of closing the `root` window in your earlier version, by making each popup window have a way of exiting out, since it won't run `do_next()` unless the button is pressed.

```
from Tkinter import *

name_list = ["Jimmy Bob", " Bobby Jim", "Sammy Jim Bob" ] 

def assign():
    global e1, win
    print("You chose option %s" %(e1.get()))
    win.destroy() 
    do_next()

def quit():
    global root
    root.destroy()

def do_next():
    global i, e1, win, root
    if i == len(name_list):
        root.destroy() 
        return
    win = Toplevel(root)
    win.lift()                                             
    e1 = Entry(win)
    e1.grid(row=1, column=0)
    var = StringVar()
    var.set(name_list[i])
    Label(win, textvariable = var).grid(row=0, column=0)
    Button(win, text='Enter Real Name', command=assign).grid(row=2, column=0, pady=4)
    win.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",quit)    
    i += 1

i = 0
root = Tk() 
root.withdraw()
do_next()
root.mainloop()
```

some other things to note: if you're including this as part of a larger script I would encapsulate the entire popup procedure in a specialized class in order to avoid using globals